# Cordova iOs error

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-ios

I’m using platform Cordova to create iOs, Android and Windows App. I tried to learn all about Cordova, and I consider myself very good using the tool.

After I upgrade xCode 6.4 to 7 I got a issue. The problem happens when I try to build my iOs App in the terminal. I got an error in this error create some extra conflicts, see again the build:

// ERROR
AppDelegate.m:138:1: warning: conflicting return type in implementation of
      'application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:': 'UIInterfaceOrientationMask' (aka 'enum UIInterfaceOrientationMask') vs 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int')
      [-Wmismatched-return-types]
// ERROR

I've been looking at many forums and still can not find solution.
Can somebody help me to fix this problem?

Comment: It's just a warning, shouldn't break anything. It's been fixed and will be included on the next cordova release, but you can edit the AppDelegate line 138 and make it return UIInterfaceOrientationMask instead of NSUInteger

Comment: I can't write Objetive-C. Can you help me with the patch?

Comment: Just go to the line 138 and switch NSUInteger to UIInterfaceOrientationMask

Comment: - (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(nullable UIWindow *)window  NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);

I did but the error persist!

Comment: Thank you jcesarmobile, i found all the NSUInteger i try one by one, and fix the error. I thing everything is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Don't feel bad. Whenever Xcode and iOS are updated, all sorts of stuff breaks for experienced and inexperienced people alike. I would try updating everything related to building Cordova apps: cordova, ios-sim, ios-deploy, etc.

Be sure to perform the updates and make a backup first, but sometimes removing and re-adding a platform will resolve random issues also. Try:

```
cordova platform rm ios
cordova platform add ios
```

Comment: I want to know if this is happen to everyone or just to me :P Im afraid to learn Objetive-C... Im a web designer frontend/backend so... Cordova is the best way for me...